# How do I pad a pyspark column array like numpy?

Tags: numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, large-data

I need to make a copy of a column on pyspark and pad it 1 at the top to shift the column down by 1. Here is an example:
**old df**

```
       ID  |   count|
+----------+--------+
|        11| 1666030|
|        01|   21924|
|        99| 1487407|
|        09|43905646|
|        02|   21420|
```

**desired result**

```
       ID  |   count|  paddedID  |
+----------+--------+------------+
|        11| 1666030|    00      |
|        01|   21924|    11      |
|        99| 1487407|    01      |
|        09|43905646|    99      |
|        02|   21420|    09      |
```

This can be accomplished fairly easily with the *np.pad()* function but not sure how I can do it over a large data set on pyspark.
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
There is a sortable time column (not shown in this toy example here) where we will use to make sure the shift happens the same every time. Thanks for pointing this out everyone.

Comment: it's hard to achieve what you desire given the input df is unordered, and spark operations are done randomly, not in the input order. spark is distributed by nature and the data is distributed, so one can't be sure of a sequence of partition to operate

Comment: @samkart, we do have a sortable column to keep the data in order prior to this operation. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `lag()` window function to get the desired result.

1. Importing necessary packages:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, lag
```

2. Convert your Pandas DataFrame to Spark DataFrame

```
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pandasdf)
sdf.show()
```

```
+---+--------+
| ID|   count|
+---+--------+
| 11| 1666030|
| 01|   21924|
| 99| 1487407|
| 09|43905646|
| 02|   21420|
+---+--------+
```

3. Add a new column `paddedID` with the previous value of each record, using `lag()` window function

```
window_spec = Window.orderBy(lit(0))

sdf.withColumn("paddedID", lag("ID", 1, "00").over(window_spec)).show()
```

***Output***

```
+---+--------+--------+
| ID|   count|paddedID|
+---+--------+--------+
| 11| 1666030|      00|
| 01|   21924|      11|
| 99| 1487407|      01|
| 09|43905646|      99|
| 02|   21420|      09|
+---+--------+--------+
```

Comment: note this is not deterministic. Spark dataframe is unordered so you cannot guarantee to have the same result every run unless you have a sortable column.

Comment: @Emma if Spark DF order is non-deterministic, is the OP's question answerable?

Comment: @PaulH Not unless OP has a sortable column. if OP has some datetime columns that is not shown in the question, this answer will help achieving it by changing the `orderBy` part.

Comment: @PaulH Yes that can be done, if you have a row unique identifier in your Pandas DataFrame, like datetime or a row number can be quite useful.

Comment: I do have a datetime column that is sortable. :) Thanks guys